# Compare home and away scores. Then update another column with the winner's name (home or away)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table Games

`id  |  visitor  | score1 |   home   | score2 |  winner
------+-----------+--------+----------+--------+----------
    1 | abc       |     20 | xyz      |     15 |
    2 | def       |     31 | uvw      |     29 |
    3 | ghi       |     30 | rst      |     25 |
    4 | jkl       |     16 | lmn      |     27 |
    5 | lmn       |     15 | opq      |     21 |
    6 | opq       |     14 | jkl      |     16 |
    7 | rst       |      9 | ghi      |     41 |
    8 | uvw       |     10 | def      |     21 |
    9 | xyz       |     23 | abc      |     19 |`

How would I iterate over each row and compare the visitor and home teams' points and then update the winner column with the winner's name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A regular update with a `CASE` does it well;

```
UPDATE games 
  SET winner = CASE WHEN score1 > score2 THEN visitor
                    WHEN score2 > score1 THEN home
                    ELSE 'tie' END;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c3ee49/1).